# How to add a route to the map?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a android app. There is a record route feature. I recorded the coordinates, how can I add the route to the map? I tried this but not work.

```
 Polyline route = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
    .add(latlng1, latlng2, latlng3, latlng4, latlng5)
    .width(10)
    .color(Color.argb(255, 255, 150, 0)));
```

Comment: Please define "not work"

Comment: The route don't appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `Polyline` route may be hidden under the map. You need to set the Z index of the `Polyline` route.

```
route.setZIndex(100000);
```